# Ideas for Door Opening that is 1 foot above adjoining room

Tags: doors, stairs, remodeling

I am renovating and add-on room at my house.  The room is a converted outdoor patio which has concrete slab for flooring.  In order to add a bathroom (toilet & drop-in shower combo), the decision was made to build the bathroom ABOVE the concrete which made it easier because no concrete had to be disturbed.

The trade off is that the bathroom and its opening now sits 1 foot ABOVE the room floor.  For privacy reasons, as well as ventilation -- I now want to ensure that the opening can be CLOSED, which means some type of door.  Problem is the 1 foot "step" up someone has to take to get into the bathroom currently.

I see 3 options:

1. **Regular door.**  Issue here is that the extra 12 inches put the door frame  height well above 80' inches.
2. **Regular door w/ step.**  I could frame a regular door if I start at the stop of the step (1 ft up), but what to do with the steep step into the bathroom?  Do I build a small set of steps (or a single step) up to 1 ft?  Also -- since the bathroom is small, the door can't really swing INSIDE the bathroom, and it needs to swing OUT, which would make the door swing over the steps.  Not sure what to do there.
3. **Pocket door or Barn door.**  Some type of sliding door might be called for, but I would have to demo part of the wall for the pocket and I would have to figure out a creative solution for the step up if I went with either option.

Appreciate some ideas here!

Comment: Are you sure you need a whole foot (why can't the plumbing run between or through the bathroom floor joists).  If it will be 12", that is too much for a single step.  You will need 2 steps, with the top step forming a landing outside the door (it's dangerous to have a drop-off behind a door).  Each step would be approx 12" deep.  Put a standard height door into the bathroom at the top of the steps, or a standard height door in another wall at the base of the steps.  (cont'd)

Comment: At the top, a pocket or barn door would make sense because there isn't room on either side for a door to swing.  A barn door wouldn't require breaking up the existing wall.  At the bottom, a regular door could swing into the room.